# Getting x number of variables in mod_rewrite from "directories"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This rewrite rule works fine for domain.com/news but I would like be able to parse multiple levels into variables like  domain.com/news/2012/party/zeke etc

I tried experimenting with the regex but failed badly.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Also tried solutions here:
[mod_rewrite with multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789944/mod-rewrite-with-multiple-variables)

[using mod_rewrite to simulate multiple sub-directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282566/using-mod-rewrite-to-simulate-multiple-sub-directories)

// EDIT:  It seems I can just add one rule per level BUT is it possibel to have one rule that does all levels?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /page.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /page.php?page=$1&sub=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have recursive rules however all of the parts of your rewrite are data. So how can it be converted to a query string as it does not know how to name the variables.

If you had `/section/news/year/2012/user/zeke/` then you could use (**NOT TESTED**):-

```
RewriteRule ^section/\w+/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$      news/$3?$1=$2 [NC,N,QSA]
RewriteRule ^section/(\w+)/?$                       page.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

This should end up rewriting to `page.php?page=news&year=2012&user=zeke

With what you are trying to do you are going to have to change your requirements and use a version of the above or pass them all down to a page in PHP and do the work in PHP.

Comment: Thank you! I'm upgrading my cms and this will be a big help.