# How to used regular expression to match one or more levels directory in mod_rewrite?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br />
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br />
RewriteRule ^(.\*)/(.\*)$ web/$1.php [L]<br />

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br />
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br />
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1.php [L]<br />
```

I want the following URLs

> http://www.example.com/**index**
>
> http://www.example.com/**index**/
>
> http://www.example.com/**index**/admin
>
> http://www.example.com/**index**/admin/
>
> http://www.example.com/**index**/admin/123......

all redirect to

> http://www.example.com/web/**index.php**

but if use my code,
it cannot redirect more than two levels directory...
How can I adjust the .htaccess file?

Comment: Have a look at the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282566/using-mod-rewrite-to-simulate-multiple-sub-directories.

Comment: I already see this answer you paste, but it cannot solve my question.(Maybe I didn't get enough skill about it). Because I need to get the variable like "index" to redirect to "web/index.php"

Comment: What do you want to happen to the /admin/123 stuff?

Comment: Oh~ the /admin/123 is a example, actually I am trying to find some situation for practice.

Comment: I think maybe I can make the /index/admin/123 redirect to /web/index.php with "admin" and "123" two variable. So, I have to match the "index" string first.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^/index/?([A-Za-z0-9-/]*)$ /web/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

insert (.php)? if you also want to match a plain /index.php too.